# Can access go context values after cancelling?

Tags: go

Learning contexts in go. I tried a context cancellation, which tries to access a value set to the context after cancelling. To my surprise it worked:

```
    import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func test(ctx context.Context, cancelFunc context.CancelFunc){
    intervalTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2).C
    expiryTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5).C
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
            return
        case <-intervalTicker:
            fmt.Println("interval")
        case <-expiryTicker:
            fmt.Println("expiry")
            func() {
                defer cancelFunc()
                fmt.Println("Calling context cancel")
            }()
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    type key string
    var contextKey key
    parent := context.WithValue(context.TODO(), contextKey, "V1")
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithCancel(parent)
    test(ctx, cancelFunc)

    fmt.Println(ctx.Value(contextKey))
}
```

As I'm passing the same child context and the cancel function to the test function, I would have expected the context to be cancelled and the value to be not available. Isn't it so?

Comment: You've proven that it isn't so - your question answers itself. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: @Adrian I wanted to clarify. For me it seemed natural that after context cancellation, the context values are not there anymore. However I agree with the explanation provided below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`context.WithCancel`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithCancel) documentation

> The returned context's Done channel is closed when the returned cancel function is called or when the parent context's Done channel is closed, whichever happens first.

From the [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) documentation

> Done returns a channel that's closed when work done on behalf of this context should be canceled.

Cancelling a context is not supposed to mean anything like "destroy this context", or "make this context not usable anymore". It is purely to *signal* to users of the context that the work should be cancelled. This signal is not magic, and must be explicitly checked for.

Consider this situation:

```golang
select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    return
default:
    value := ctx.Value("something")
    doSomething(value)
}
```

Now imagine that context works as you're imagining, where upon cancelling, values are no longer retrievable.  This situation now is possible:

```golang
select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    return
default:
    // OH NO! Even though we just checked and it was ok,
    // some other goroutine called cancel() right at this moment!
    value := ctx.Value("something")
    // Now "value" is going to be invalid.
    doSomething(value)
}
```

The existing model for context is helpful because it allows the work routine to only check the context status at specific checkpoints which are safest or most convenient, and not worry about it in other cases.